# Doxygen: how to describe class member variables in php?

Tags: php, variables, doxygen

I'm trying to use doxygen to parse php code into xml output.
Doxygen does not parse description of class member variables.

Here is my sample php file:

```
<?php
class A
{
    /**
      * Id on page.
      *
      * @var integer
      */
    var $id = 1;
}
?>
```

Note that comment has a brief description and variable type.
Here is xml i got from this source:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<doxygen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd" version="1.7.2">
  <compounddef id="class_a" kind="class" prot="public">
<compoundname>A</compoundname>
  <sectiondef kind="public-attrib">
  <memberdef kind="variable" id="class_a_1ae97941710d863131c700f069b109991e" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
    <type></type>
    <definition>$id</definition>
    <argsstring></argsstring>
    <name>$id</name>
    <initializer> 1</initializer>
    <briefdescription>
    </briefdescription>
    <detaileddescription>
    </detaileddescription>
    <inbodydescription>
    </inbodydescription>
    <location file="C:/projects/version6-7/asprunner/PHP/source/classes/a.php" line="11" bodyfile="C:/projects/version6-7/asprunner/PHP/source/classes/a.php" bodystart="11" bodyend="-1"/>
  </memberdef>
  </sectiondef>
<briefdescription>
</briefdescription>
<detaileddescription>
</detaileddescription>
<location file="C:/projects/version6-7/asprunner/PHP/source/classes/a.php" line="5" bodyfile="C:/projects/version6-7/asprunner/PHP/source/classes/a.php" bodystart="4" bodyend="12"/>
<listofallmembers>
  <member refid="class_a_1ae97941710d863131c700f069b109991e" prot="public" virt="non-virtual"><scope>A</scope><name>$id</name></member>
</listofallmembers>
  </compounddef>
</doxygen>
```

Neither description or type were parsed.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using an input filter to insert typehints from the @var annotation inline with variable declaration, and remove the @var annotation as it has different meaning in Doxygen. For more info, see bug [#626105](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626105).

As Doxygen uses C-like parser, when the input filter is run it can recognize types.

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

$regexp = '#\@var\s+([^\s]+)([^/]+)/\s+(var|public|protected|private)\s+(\$[^\s;=]+)#';
$replac = '${2} */ ${3} ${1} ${4}';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replac, $source);

echo $source;
```

This is a [quick hack](http://xkcd.com/208/), and probably have bugs, it just works for my code:

[image: Doxygen @var PHP]

You can enable input filter with [INPUT_FILTER](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) option in your Doxyfile. Save the code above to file named php_var_filter.php and set the filter value to "php php_var_filter.php".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I've created a simple input filter which turns the basic syntax of

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
public $id;
```

into

```
/**
 * @var int $id
 */
public $id;
```

which would be redundant anyway. This way the Eclipse IDE can use the same docblock as doxygen.

You can download the input filter from here:

https://bitbucket.org/tamasimrei/misc-tools/src/master/doxygen/filter.php

See the [doxygen Manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) on how to use an input filter.

The tool also escapes backslashes in docblocks, so you could use namespaces there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Doxygen. I've the same problem with documentation in HTML.

What currently works is:

```
class A
{
    var $id = 1; /**< Id on page. */
}
```

But these comments are not recognized by NetBeans IDE as documentation of field.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to your question: If you are at liberty to use the right tool for the job, have a look at [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org). It also generates an XML-document for further transformation into HTML or any other display format and works very good for PHP. It won't break your usual docblock-usage either.

As an example output, check out the [Zend Framework API documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Guess I'll be using DocBlox from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

The block will be associated correctly if you omit @var. That doesn't give anywhere to declare the type, which is annoying, but at least the description will work.

Test version: Doxygen 1.7.1

Comment: This appears to be the best solution at the moment - I asked the folks on the Doxygen mailing list, who replied with the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Goran for his doxygen filter! Extending the same idea a bit, to make proper documentation of function parameters as well:

Include Zend Studio-style array-of-objects @param types in doxygen documentation:

```
// Change the following:
// /** @param VarType[] $pParamName Description **/
// function name(array $pParamName) {

// Into:
// /** @param array $pParamName Description **/
// function name(VarType[] $pParamName) {
$regexp = '#\@param\s+([^\s]+)\[\]\s+(\$[^\s]+)\s+([^/]+)/\s+(public|protected|private)?\s+function\s+([^\s]+)\s*\(([^)]*)array\s+\2([^)]*)\)(\s+){#s';
$replac = '@param array ${2} ${3}/ ${4} function ${5} (${6} ${1}[] ${2}${7})${8}{';
$lSource = preg_replace($regexp, $replac, $lSource);
```

Include int/float/double/string @param types in doxygen documentation:

```
// Change the following:
// /** @param (int|float|double|string) $pParamName Description **/
// function name($pParamName) {

// Into:
// /** @param (int|float|double|string) $pParamName Description **/
// function name((int|float|double|string) $pParamName) {
$regexp = '#\@param\s+(int|float|double|string)\s+(\$[^\s]+)\s+([^/]+)/\s+(public|protected|private)?\s+function\s+([^\(\s]+)\s*([^)]*)(\(|,)\s*\2([^)]*)\)(\s+){#s';

$replac = '@param ${1} ${2} ${3}/ ${4} function ${5}${6}${7}${1} ${2}${8})${9}{ '; //${6}${1} ${2}${7})${8}{';
$lSource = preg_replace($regexp, $replac, $lSource);
```

Both of the above regexps also naturally work with functions taking more than one argument. Also just a quick hack, which works for our code, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Does it **really** work with multiple argument functions and make correct "edits" in **both** places for **each** parameter, regardless of whether the PHP type hint was originally given for it?

Answer (score 0):

For windows users without installed php may be usefull use [compiled to executable php_var_filter.php doxygen filter script](http://yadi.sk/d/lN-0CQ8T5cLdY)  from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8472180/2466932)