# Is there a way to get doxygen work with array short syntax (PHP 5.4)

Tags: php, arrays, doxygen

Since PHP 5.4 there is a short syntax for arrays.
One can write `$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];` insted of `$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);`

But if you have something like this:

```
class Test
{
   /**
    * brief description
    * @var array $arr
    */
   $arr = [  0 => [ ... ], 2 => [ ... ]  ];
}
```

then doxygen does not show an initializer line or only something like `[ 0 => [ ... ]`.

By now I have a lot of code only using the short syntax and I don't want to change this for a documentation tool.

Is there any way to teach doxygen to use `[...]` as `array( ... )`? I'm using doxygen 1.8.7

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**
I had an idea, that the problem could be a line break, if I write it like this

```
   $arr = [  0 => [ ... ], 
             2 => [ ... ]  ];
```

I tested this, but no effect. But if I left out the first comma, it works fine (with and without the line break). But if I left out the comma, it is obviously a syntax error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: do you have array in the `0=>[...]`

Comment: just in some. But no one of the folowing cases works: `0=>[]`, `0=>[1]`, `0=>[0=>[...]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a while but I found a way myself. Maybe someone has the same problem, so I post my solution here.

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8472180/3440545) to another question and I wrote a filter that changes
`public $var = [ ... ];` to `public $var = array( ... );`

Doxygen than will show the array and everything inside correctly.

```
<?php 

$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

$regexp = '#(var|public|protected|private)\s+(\$[^\s;=]+)\s+\=\s+\[([\s\S]*?)\]\;#';
$replac = '${1} ${2} = array( ${3} );';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replac, $source);

echo $source;

?>
```

[Here](http://regexr.com/38vqi) is a preview of the regex.

You can find some more input filters to improve doxygen's php support on [GitHub](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters).